# Share image with whatsapp

Tags: android

I want to share image from my app with whatsapp. I completed that task but the image I am sharing has a big layout in whatsapp. I want images to be shown in smaller size. Is it possible to make a custom layout in android containing images with text and then sharing layout with whatsapp.

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoKwC.png)
I want something like the upper image but all I managed to get is below one.

Comment: What do you mean by big layout? However if you just want to re size the image you can call .scale on it

Comment: Share your code. Post screenshots if necessary.

Comment: added image plz check.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Intent and Send Data with Intent to the Whatsapp Package

```
  whatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "URL You Want To Share");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            if (isPackageExisted("com.whatsapp"))
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() , "Whatsapp is not installed" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and the isPackagedExisted Function

```
  public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i already tried 1st part but output is not as per requirement. what is 2nd part used for,can u elaborate plz

Comment: second part is a function to check if the whatsapp installed in the device or not